# загрузка данных перед созданием активити

Tags: java, android, activity

В активити находится ViewPager, которому при создании нужны данные с сервера. В методе onCreate посылается запрос на сервер для загрузки этих данных, но они не успевают загрузиться, как можно рационально решить проблему?

Comment: как загружаете данные с сервера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте AsyncTask который будет запускаться в вашем Activity и запрашивать данные с сервера, сделайте ProgressBar для отображения того, что идет операция, как только AsyncTask завершит свою работу создавайте ViewPager со своими фрагментами.